# How to convert the selected index value of a dropdown list into an integer

Tags: asp.net

I have one dropdown list containing the list as 1,2,3,4,5... and the 0th index as empty.
I want to set the 0th index(empty space) to an integer.
0th index value is assigned as string. How can i set to a int variable?

I had selected the 0th index to an integer value, as
int value= 0;

Later i need to set as 
if(value ==0)
value =" ";

if value= 0, it should not display anything. How to do in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown has collection of [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The `type` of Value attribute of [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could not be changed, You can assign it integer value as a string and retrieve and convert to integer when you need.

```
ddlBirthDay.Items[0].Value = "0";
```

You can later convert it to integer.

```
int value = int.Parse(ddlBirthDay.Items[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to CONVERT the selected value to integer, you can try to parse it:

```
int SelectedVal = int.Parse(MyDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: You should have used TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int value = Int.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.ToString());
```